# jQuery formatting not applying to ajax data despite referesh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am loading a list view inside a collapsible from the server (php file) via a GET response message. However, jQuery formatting is not being applied to the added HTML despite refreshing the jQuery element

My page is here : http://i.cs.hku.hk/~hsbashir/Project_Work/events/events.html

**HTML Code (relevant code only)**

```
<script>
lastRecord=0;

    function loadEvents(){

        $('#sample').html( 'hello' );
        $.get(
        "eventquery.php?lastRecord="+lastRecord,
        function( data ) {
            $('#loadCollapsible').append( data )
            .listview( 'refresh' );
            }); 

    }
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color : #e9e9e9;" onload="loadEvents()">

<div data-iconpos="none" data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
    <h2><img src="today_calendar.png" style="height: 60px; vertical-align:middle;"> Today's Events </h2>
    <div id="loadCollapsible">
    <!-- Load from php -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**PHP Code (relevant code only)**

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        print '<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">';

        print '<h5>'.$row['Title'].'<h5>';
        print ' <ul data-role="listview">';
        print '<li><a href="#">';
        print '<table><tr><td>Date</td>';
        print '<td style="padding: 10px;">'.$row['Date'].'</td>';
        print '</tr><tr>';
        print '<td> Time </td>';
        print '<td style="padding: 10px;">'.$row['Time_Duration'].'</td>';
        print '</tr><tr>';
        print '<td> Venue </td>';
        print '<td style="padding: 10px;">'.$row['Venue'].'</td>';
        print '</tr></table></a></li>';
        print '<li style="background-color: #CADECC;">';
        print '<button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-calendar" style="width: 170px; float: right; position: relative;">Add to calendar</button>';
        print '</li></ul>'; 

        print '</div>';
    }
```

Comment: Try create instead of refresh

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Mobile listview must first be initialized before calling the refresh method.

Because you're loading the list with ajax it doesn't get initialized automatically. Try this:

```
function loadEvents(){

        $('#sample').html( 'hello' );
        $.get(
        "eventquery.php?lastRecord="+lastRecord,
        function( data ) {
            $('#loadCollapsible').append( data );
            $('#loadCollapsible ul').listview().listview( 'refresh' );
            }); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user1672694. This code works by changing the function `loadEvents()` in HTML:

```
function loadEvents(){

    $('#sample').html( 'hello' );
    $.get(
    "eventquery.php?lastRecord="+lastRecord,
    function( data ) {
        $('#loadCollapsible').append( data )
        .trigger( 'create' )    
        .listview( 'refresh' );
        });         
}
```